# Doctrine 2 Common 2.5 - where is the Cache classes?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I use Doctrine 2 in my project with ZF1. Because I've got quite old version of Doctrine, today I'd like to update it. I've checked the Common package:

https://github.com/doctrine/common/tree/master/lib/Doctrine/Common

but I see the whole "cache" directory with classes for caching just disappeared. Why? Is is not longer support by Doctrine or should I download it separately?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2.4.1, the cache was extracted into a seperate component, see 
https://github.com/doctrine/common/commit/0e178880c4eb8b6131e98c7a410b7a05a0574943

You will find the component here, naming of the classes is still the same:
https://github.com/doctrine/cache